# User agent: PHP parsing, browscap and nonconventional "browsers"

Tags: php, ms-office, user-agent, browscap

I am looking for a reliable way to find out what user agent is requesting my PHP page(s).  I'm aware of `get_browser` as well as `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` but neither seems to be reliable.

With `get_browser`, you need browscap PHP directive set to an ini file defining user agents.  PHP recommends this one - http://browsers.garykeith.com/downloads.asp - so I installed the "full" one specified for LAMP.

It works great with `get_browser` for your usual mix of browsers, but I am specifically dealing with requests from MS Office.  In that case, it seems to return nothing, like with OS X Excel (note: `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` is the first line, followed by array output of `get_browser`):

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X) Excel/14.0.0

Array
(
    [browser_name_regex] =     ^.*$
    [browser_name_pattern] =     *
    [browser] =     Default Browser
    [version] =     0
    [majorver] =     0
    [minorver] =     0
    [platform] =     unknown
    [alpha] =     
    [beta] =     
    [win16] =     
    [win32] =     
    [win64] =     
    [frames] =     
    [iframes] =     
    [tables] =     
    [cookies] =     
    [backgroundsounds] =     
    [javascript] =     
    [vbscript] =     
    [javaapplets] =     
    [activexcontrols] =     
    [isbanned] =     
    [ismobiledevice] =     
    [issyndicationreader] =     
    [crawler] =     
    [cssversion] =     0
    [aolversion] =     0
)
```

To make matters worse, it seems to not even mention Office on some Windows cases:

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)

Array
(
    [browser_name_regex] =     ^mozilla/4\.0 (compatible; msie 7\.0.*; .*windows nt 6\.1.*).*$
    [browser_name_pattern] =     Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0*; *Windows NT 6.1*)*
    [parent] =     IE 7.0
    [platform] =     Win7
    [browser] =     IE
    [version] =     7.0
    [majorver] =     7
    [win32] =     1
    [frames] =     1
    [iframes] =     1
    [tables] =     1
    [cookies] =     1
    [backgroundsounds] =     1
    [javascript] =     1
    [vbscript] =     1
    [javaapplets] =     1
    [activexcontrols] =     1
    [cssversion] =     2
    [minorver] =     0
    [alpha] =     
    [beta] =     
    [win16] =     
    [win64] =     
    [isbanned] =     
    [ismobiledevice] =     
    [issyndicationreader] =     
    [crawler] =     
    [aolversion] =     0
)
```

Judging by these examples, it seems that `get_browser` is actually less reliable here and more information can be gathered from `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` which at least spits out a bunch of .NET references for the Office requests.

With that in mind, can anyone point me to a well written function that breaks down `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`?  Every search I ran ends up with recommendations to use `get_browser` instead.

Any thoughts on why `get_browser` seems to fail at referencing MS Office at all from Windows based installations are welcome too... here are 10 tests of various users clicking links in different Office apps (`$_SERVER` first then `get_browser` result): http://pastebin.com/5m2zWMrt - notice the lack of any signs of office after the first three examples from OS X.  I also asked a related question over at MSDN: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officegeneral/thread/8ad594cd-0dfe-4110-8ffc-4d0caee4c29f

To sum it up, I'd like to get a short term solution going with a good parser of `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`, ideally one that can figure out if the request is coming from MS Office.  In the long term, I need to figure out why `get_browser` doesn't work with MS Office despite having an up-to-date ini with Office data.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply not possible for the server to correctly guess which browser/app it's talking to, as the provided user agents are - as you've discovered for yourself - unreliable to say the least. It's pretty easy to write a user agent parser for the most used browsers - but then but about the rest? MS Office, for instance?

So no, just don't try to guess the browser from the server side. 'Cause that's what you're doing, guessing - not knowing.

Why do you need to know the browser's make and model anyway? If it's to adapt the page because of which browser the user has, you should instead use [CSS conditional comments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment) and/or testing which features can be relied on with JavaScript. Be creative, and do everything else, just don't try to *guess* the browser.

Comment: I'd be happy with a best-guess for MS Office or NOT MS Office.  The reason is because we have many documents that reference members-only pages, and when you click a link inside Office it resolves the final page after any redirects, including redirects telling you this page is members-only.  So Office then gives that final destination to a real browser, and our logged-in member gets the you're-not-a-member error.

I can think of multiple ways to solve this, but one would involve guessing what the user agent is... so a nice parser for the `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` output would be handy here.

Comment: @lioman Are you saying you want to use the User-Agent header for purposes of authentication, essentially? If so, I really wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: @deceze No, I will simply not redirect people to any error messages if I know the request came from Office, because then Office will get the right URL back even though it cannot see the contents of my page - but it will pass the right URL to the browser, which is authenticated to see that page.

Comment: It could seem to me, that you could just let your users log in when the page is finally shown in the browser then?
And BTW, if you *must* mingle with the user agent, why don't you just write a parser that tells you if the client's specifically MS Office or not?

Comment: My original question asks for a parser that can figure out if MS Office is the UA.